# Passing value to another action result

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor

i am receiving Emplid in this action,  (called from DDL action which contains Submit btn and Drop down)

```
public ActionResult showDDL(int? EmplID = null) 
        {
            ViewBag.EmplID = EmplID;
            if (EmplID == null) 
            {
                IEnumerable<GetAtdRecord_SpResult> EmployeeAtd_2 = DataContext.GetAtdRecord_Sp(0).ToList();
                return View(EmployeeAtd_2);
            }
            else if (EmplID != null) 
            {
                IEnumerable<GetAtdRecord_SpResult> EmployeeAtd_2 = DataContext.GetAtdRecord_Sp(EmplID).ToList();
                return View(EmployeeAtd_2);
            }

            return View();
        }
```

View:

```
@{

     var grid = new WebGrid(ViewData.Model, defaultSort: "EmplID", rowsPerPage: 20);

  }

@if (Model.Count > 0)
{
  <div id="AllEmpGrid_ByName">
   @grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
                                        grid.Column("EmplID", "Employee ID"),
                                        grid.Column("EmplName", "Employee Name"),
                                        grid.Column("ShiftID", "Shift ID"),
                                        grid.Column("DateVisited", "Date of Visit"),
                                        grid.Column("InTime", "In Time"),
                                        grid.Column("TimeOut", "Time Out"),
                                        grid.Column("OverTime", "Over Time"),
                                        grid.Column("TotalWorkingTime", "Total Working Time")
                                      ))
 </div>

 using (Html.BeginForm("ToExcel", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
 {
   <button type="submit" class="button_form button_download" >Download in Excel</button>
 }

}
else
{
    <h2 class="error" >No Data Found</h2> 
}
```

In same View you can see, button DOWNLOAD IN EXCEL, i want to pass this emplID to ToExcel method

```
public ActionResult ToExcel(int? empid )
        {
            var DataContext = new EmployeeRecordDataContext();

            var grid = new GridView();
            grid.DataSource = DataContext.GetAtdRecord_Sp(null).ToList();
            grid.DataBind();

            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=AttendanceSheet.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

            Response.Charset = "";
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);

            grid.RenderControl(htw);

            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
            return RedirectToAction("index");
        }
```

i can't figure out that how to pass EmplID recieved in Action 'showDDL' to EmpID when i click Button "Download in Excel" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this using ViewBag. First store the value in ViewBag.

```
public ActionResult showDDL(int? EmplID = null) 
{
   ViewBag.Id = EmplId;
   // You other logic....
}
```

And then use it on your form like this -

```
 using (Html.BeginForm("ToExcel", "Home", new { empid = ViewBag.Id }, FormMethod.Get))
 {
   <button type="submit" class="button_form button_download" >Download in Excel</button>
 }
```

And one the server you can get the Value in the parameter -

```
public ActionResult ToExcel(int? empid)
{
    // You logic and use empid here...
}
```